# EF 6 calls INSERT instead of UPDATE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This could be a duplicate question but a lot of searching for the words in the title only got me a lot of unrelated results.

I have an entity that's roughly set up like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public GUID AId { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The context has `public DbSet<B> BInstances { get; set; }` for `B` objects. In `OnModelCreating`, the mapping has `A` set to ignored and `B` is mapped to a table called `TableB`.

The `AId` field is not auto-generated (not an identity field) but it's set to be primary key, both in the database and in the mapping. In the database, the field is defined as a non-null `uniqueidentifier` with no default.

At runtime, I'm loading an instance of `B` using its key (`_token` is just a `CancellationToken`):

```
var b = await (dbCtx.BInstances.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.AId), _token));
```

Then, a property of `b` is set and I try to save it back to database:

```
b.SomeOtherProperty = "some new text";
await (dbCtx.SaveChangesAsync(_token));
```

At this point, I'm getting a *Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint* error from the database, stating that the value of `AId` cannot be inserted because it'd be a duplicate. Of course, the ID is already in the database, I loaded the entity from there, using the ID. For some reason, EF generates an INSERT statement, not an UPDATE and I don't understand why.

When I check `dbCtx.Entry(b).State`, it's already set to `EntityState.Modified`. I'm at a loss - can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I never had issues with updating entities before but I haven't used EF with GUID primary keys (usually I use `long` primary keys).

I'm using EF 6 and .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. There are a few reasons why this can occur, and a complete end to end sample will point us in the right direction.

Comment: @mjwills I'll try that but only can do it in the morning (it's late night here). My real code is a bit longer and is under an NDA so I'll have to put something together. I spent the past 4-5 hours trying to understand why it fails.

Comment: Can you post how you have defined the entity `B` mapping in `OnModelCreating` method?

Comment: @user1672994 I will post it in the morning - I need to get some sleep, I was just checking in one last time.

Comment: I would except not this entity is making the problem (unless some place in the code actually sets the state of the entry to Added), but a navigation property. Could also be an issue with the provider, that's somewhat unlikely though. Without the verifiable example that's just a guess though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions - this turned out to be a mapping problem that I caused.

In my `OnModelCreating()` call, I called `MapInheritedProperties()` on a type that didn't inherit from a base class (other than `object`, of course) - this seems to have triggered a problem. Other entities that do share a base class worked fine with the mapping call.

I also called `ToTable()` directly against the entity class - this broke my table mapping for reasons I do not understand. Once I moved that call inside `Map()`, it started working as expected.

So I went from this:

```
entity.ToTable("tablename");
```

to this:

```
entity.Map(m => m.ToTable("tablename"));
```

to solve the problem.

Hopefully this will be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
b.SomeOtherProperty = "some new text";
dbCtx.BInstances.AddOrUpdate(b);
await (dbCtx.SaveChangesAsync(_token));
```

AddorUpdate will update your b instance if it is already added.